# Why is my notification getting cleared?

Tags: android

I have tried `.setAutoCancel(false) and .setOngoing(true);` but why does my notification still get cleared when I swipe it? here is my code-

```
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.download)
            .setContentTitle("Download[ROOT]")
            // .setContentText("This is a test notification")
            .setAutoCancel(false).setOngoing(true);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DownloaderRoot.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(111, builder.build());
```

I have tried adding flags as well-

```
// Add as notification
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notif = builder.build();// add flag support
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        manager.notify(111, builder.build());
```

Comment: what do u mean swipe it?? close the app..?

Comment: swipe it from status bar

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Notification notif = builder.build();
notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
manager.notify(111, notif);
```